# What read protection method is available in RP2040?

Tags: security, pi-pico, readwrite

I went through the data sheet but could not find any specific details about read protection. If anyone has worked on that specific area in RP2040, then can you please give your inputs about it?

Comment: what read you wish to protect?

Comment: the source code of the product?

Comment: I see.  You can compile your C/C++ code and give only the compiled version. Even for MicroPython code, you can also "compile" it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no read/copy protection.

Since the RP2040 has no internal flash, all compiled code is stored in an external QSPI flash and executed 'in-place'.

See: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/618020/code-protection-firmware-security-in-pi-pico-rp2040